# Сборка Linux с нуля

Tags: linux

Хочу собрать Linux с нуля ...
Подскажите с каких библиотек начинать ...
Спасибо ...

Comment: Гуглим: `lfs`, `linux from scratch`, потом `blfs`, `beyond linux from scratch` ;)

Comment: Linux From Scratch в руки и вперёд

Comment: LinuxFromScratch очень объёмный том , а мне как новичку желательно - самое-самое ...

Comment: в proot собрать можно, но запустить не получится. для минимального линукса нужен только busybox

Comment: скачиваете и распаковываете исходники программы `linux`, в каталоге с распакованными исходниками запускаете программу `make`. всё.

Comment: Что , так просто ? Программа make станет подключать другие программы , а если их нет ? Тут нужна точность ... Где брать исходники зависимостей ? Если нет , то хотя-бы их названия ...

Comment: какие ещё «другие программы»/«зависимости»? вы спрашиваете, как скомпилировать программу linux. одну программу. я вам написал, как это сделать.

Answer (score 3):

Для новичка можно начать с openwrt. Там готовый набор для сборки - понижает порог входа в лоу левел.

Установи sdk, настрой для сборки образа под qemu (запустится и на других виртуалках).

Собери - научись запускать образ.

Сними все галочки в списке пакетов для сборки, добавляй по одному - смотри какой что дает. Изучи инит (там на баше - все просто)

Убери базовые пакеты опенврт, напиши свой инит. Добавь удев и/или системд, а может статические файлы устройств плюс busybox init будет ближе.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы на самом деле порекомендовал Gentoo.

Это не то чтобы совсем с нуля, но поверьте, это увлекательно.
Я не открывал handbook уже лет 7 наверное, а сейчас я смотрю он стал очень увлекателен и понятен для чтения.

В общем вам сюда

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/ru

Gentoo это прям своего рода философия. Но раз вы задаете вопрос, мой ответ именно таков :)